# Why does the TextBlocks in the ListBox duplicate when i click on one of the Textblocks?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a simple MultiSelection enabled ListBox that contains TextBlocks. Now when i click one of the TextBlocks all the items in the ListBox duplicates and the clicked item is not selected. Also the multiselection does not work as it seems the list are getting refreshed. if i where to click again they are not duplicated but multiselection still does not work. I do not understand this wierd behaviour and i have read myself blind on my code.

Why are the items getting duplicated when i click one of them and why are the selection of items not working?

EDIT:

As i was debugging further i came to the source off the SelectionChanged and i managed to get by this by testing te see if the Source is a TabControl which solved my problem. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
if (selectedTab.Header.ToString() == "Plugins" && e.Source is TabControl)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    RefreshPluginList();
}
```

Here is my XAML

```
<TabItem Header="Plugins">
    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="5" MinHeight="350">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="list_PluginsDragMessage" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Panel.ZIndex="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-170,0,0" Foreground="{StaticResource SuccessGreen}" IsHitTestVisible="False">Drag and drop</TextBlock>
            <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SuccessGreen}" x:Name="list_Plugins" BorderThickness="0" Background="{StaticResource BorderDarkGreen}" Foreground="White" AllowDrop="True" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</TabItem>
```

And here is the code behind

```
private void tabs_Menu_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedTab = (sender as TabControl).SelectedItem as TabItem;
    if (selectedTab.Header.ToString() == "Plugins")
    {
        RefreshPluginList();
    }
}

string PluginDirectory;

private void RefreshPluginList()
{
    list_Plugins.Items.Clear();
    PluginDirectory = Path.Combine(new string[] {
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Properties.Settings.Default.Rustserverexecutable),
        "server",
        Properties.Settings.Default.Identity,
        "oxide",
        "plugins" });
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(PluginDirectory))
    {
        list_Plugins.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
    }
}
```

Here is a couple of images

[image: List]

[image: List duplicated when left mouse button pressed on one of the items]